# How to block javascript evaluation during updating a page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am updating a page through AJAX using .rjs template. Is there any way to block evaluating javascript in rendered content (something like `:script => false` for `link_to_remote`)?

My update.rjs looks pretty much like this:

```
page.replace_html 'some_div', :partial => 'partial_with_js', :collection => @list
page.insert_html ...
(etc.)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to wrap your javascript in string, then just eval it after load.